# Does Boost provide an implementation of span for C++14?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

[`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/span) was introduced in C++20, but I'm limited to C++14 and, to a lesser extent, to Boost libraries of any version. Is there something similar in Boost?

Comment: You could just copy libstdc++'s or libc++'s implementation into your project.  `std::span` only needs c++11 support.  The is also `gsl::span` which is the originator.

Comment: [Microsoft GSL](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) requires only C++14 and has `gsl::span` which was lately modified to align with `std::span`.

Comment: I found [an example](https://github.com/tcbrindle/span).

Comment: @NathanOliver Code copy-pasting is exactly what I don't want to do, especially if it depends on some libraries' internals. It's much easier and (IMO) correct to add 3-rd party library via git submodule,  along with libraries' license, docs, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out both mentioned libraries.

Comment: @L117 While it might be more correct to add a library, ["asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The edits have been attempting to move your question away from being off-topic. If it is off-topic, then it will end up closed and deleted. We'd much rather have an on-topic question which people can answer.

Comment: @Makyen Okay, got it. Was not aware about this.

Comment: There are 2 BSL licensed single-header std::span drop-ins that look promising: [tcbrindle/span](https://github.com/tcbrindle/span) - requires C++11 and is about 600 lines; [martinmoene/span-lite](https://github.com/martinmoene/span-lite) - just requires C++ 98 but header contains 1600 lines or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Boost provide an implementation of span for C++14?

There is no span in the boost namespace. But [Boost Beast library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/introduction.html) has [`boost::beast::span`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__span/). It appears to not implement the same interface as `std::span` exactly, but is an implementation of <strike>the same</strike> similar idea.

There is also [`boost::hana::span`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Sequence.html#ga9bdde56d805517bce8e387f5bcd1887e) which is something else.

Comment: This is almost what I wanted. Except it does not provide mutable iterators ):

Comment: Well, neither does `std::span`, it's begin method is also marked `const`. So this is not actual mutable slice as I was expecting.

Comment: @L117 `std::span` iterators are mutable. But yeah, `boost::beast::span` appears to not be.

Comment: Are they? I just tried Microsoft GSL's `span`, as was suggested. It has exactly the same signature as `std::span` and I was unable to mutate values, because iterator returns `const value_type`.

Comment: So I ended up applying (temporary) terrible `const_cast` hack to make it do what I want.

Comment: @L117 'Are they?' Yes, they are. The fact that `::begin()` is declared `const` just means that invoking it never changes the internal object state. I wouldn't assess GSL's implementation as something that follows the standardization process closely. For example, they used `ssize_t` instead of `size_t` as the size type - although this doesn't make much sense and doesn't match any similar functionality in the STL. See also the cppreference example which mutate the first element through `::begin()`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/begin

Answer (score 9):

As of Boost-1.78, `boost::span` is now part of the Boost core in `<boost/core/span.hpp>` (see [Boost::span docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/span.html)). This is a C++11/14/17 compatible implementation of `std::span`.

Comment: Eccellent single-header implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately, constructors 2 and 3 of [cppreference.com documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) supports only pointer types and not generic iterators (probably due to missing `std::to_address`).