# STD wrapper arround part of std::vector (or alternatives)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stdvector

I currently use a std::vector to store some data (nb : the size is known at construction and don't changes afterwards : if you see a better structure than a vector, it's fine for me). Later in the program, I need to pass part of this data (the first N values) to an optimization function, that will modify it in place.

A simple solution would be to pass a reference to the whole vector, and an index of which part to use for optimization. But it would be nice if I could avoid telling the optimization function (and its sub-functions) which part to optimize, and just give them a vector/array/you_name_it containing only the values to be optimized.

So basically, I would like 2 "array" like objects (both constant size, but size only known at runtime) sharing the same memory.

For example, if std::vector had its members public, a simple solution would be

```C++
std::vector<int> original_vector={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
std::vector<int> sub_vector(0);
sub_vector.data=original_vector->data; //point to the same data (nb : there is no public data member, just a data() getter, and as far as I know no setter)
sub_vector.length=3;
//sub_vector now appears to contain {0,1,2}
sub_vector[1]=42;
//oringinal_vector now contains {0,42,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

Another solution would be to get the data pointer, and just pass a raw C style pointer + length to the optimization function. But it's not nice to have C pointers for arrays in C++. This could be a nice solution if there is a std container that can be initialized (without copy) by C pointer + length.

Any other ideas?

NB : I haven't written the optimizing code yet, so if it is easier, I can also put all the data to be optimized at the end instead of at the beginning.

NB : It would also be possible to create first the 2 "sub-arrays" (fixed data and data to be optimized) and then create the global array, provided there is a way without copying the data

EDIT :
for now, I'm limited at C++17, because ROS2 don't support C+20 yet

Comment: If the size is fixed at construction and never changes, consider using `std::array`.

Comment: What C++ version you're on? I'd try with `span` in the first place, be it the one from boost or std, they're pretty similar if not identical. You can also try with iterator range (i.e. begin-end pair).

Comment: the *simple solution* is to pass iterators to the function that wants to modify elements

Comment: @JesperJuhl : are you sure the size of an std::array can be set a runtime (during construction)? From what I understand, it has to be known at compile time (as it is a template argument of the array)

Comment: @alagner : yes, that is exactly what I need. Sadly I'm still stuck with C++17 as long as ROS2 don't switch to C++20, so the STD version in not available. As to using the boost version, I will have to think about it : it is definitively what I want, but include boost as dependency just for that, I don't know if it is worse it.

Comment: @Sandro In that case, look at span implementations available for C++17 (and earlier versions): [Does Boost provide an implementation of span for C++14?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60607841/580083) Note that the Boost's implementation is a single-header only, so you can use it even without installing Boost: https://github.com/boostorg/core/blob/develop/include/boost/core/span.hpp.

Comment: Or Microsoft's [`gsl::span`](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL)

Comment: using the header only version of boost seems a good solution. For the gsl version, is it compatible with linux (more precisely Jetson platforms)? And is it a heavy library like boost?

Comment: @Sandro gsl is a header-only multiplatform library.

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)?

```
std::vector<int> original_vector={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::span<int> sub_vector(original_vector.begin(), 3);
```

Comment: yes, it is what I was looking for. Excepted that sadly I'm stuck with C++17, and std::span is a C++20 feature

Comment: @Sandro you can use `gsl::span` if you have access to gsl lib

Comment: You could also look at the range_v3 library for similar functionality using iterator ranges.